# How can I reset my app's permissions?

Tags: macos, permissions

My Cocoa app requires special permission to perform some operations to access the keychain; it shows the dialog with "Always Allow", "Deny", and "Allow" buttons.

I have clicked the "Always Allow" button, but now I want to test its appearance again.

I have tried cleaning, cleaning the build folder, and resetting my app's defaults.

**How do I revoke my app's access to my keychain, so that I may test this dialog again?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch KeychainAccess.app, open the item you previously granted access to and select the `Access` tab using the segmented control in the top. You'll see a list of apps that have access to the item in the bottom where you can simply remove your app.

Comment: This worked the first time, but now I can't find any usage of my app in the entire keychain, yet it still doesn't ask for permissions :/

Comment: And now it magically works again! I think maybe macOS thought me clicking "Deny" so often placed my app in a sort of time-out, just assuming "Deny" for awhile before presenting the alert again